# How can I encrypt a PDF using Java?

Tags: java, pdf, cryptography, encryption

I have been trying to encrypt a PDF using Java. So far I can successfully encrypt other file types (.txt, .png, etc.). When I do it with PDF it breaks the info on in when I decrypt it.

This is what I'm using to encrypt it:

```
public byte[] cryptograph(Key key, byte[] content){
    Cipher cipher;
    byte[] cryptograph = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        cryptograph = cipher.doFinal(content);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cryptograph;

}
```

And this to decrypt it:

```
public byte[] decrypt(Key key,byte[] textCryp){
    Cipher cipher;
    byte[] decrypted = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        decrypted = cipher.doFinal(textCryp);
    } catch (Exception e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return decrypted;
}
```

Update:

This is what I use to read the files:

```
public byte[] getFile(){
    byte[] content = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("test.pdf");
        BufferedInputStream vf = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        content = new byte[vf.available()];
        vf.read(content);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content;
}
```

Using this to rewrite the files

```
public static void saveDecrypt(byte[] bytes) throws IOException{
        Document doc=new Document();
        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(doc,new FileOutputStream("fileDecrypted.pdf"));
            doc.open(); 
            doc.add(new Paragraph(new String(bytes)));
            doc.close();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your encryption and decryption look fine. I have to wonder if your code for reading and writing the PDF file is to blame. Can you post that?

Comment: @GabrielNetto : what did you mena by "it breaks info". Does decryption give a an exception?

Comment: The files open in the pdf reader but the text is rubish.

Comment: @GabrielNetto : can you please try this -  new Paragraph(new String(bytes,"UTF-8")?

Comment: That's not how you read all bytes from a file: `available()` doesn't give you the correct length. Use `new File("test.pdf")` and query that for the file `length()`. Then wrap the `FileInputStream(File)` with a `DataInputStream` and call `readFully()`.

Comment: Was `saveDecrypt(byte[] bytes)` supposed to decrypt the `bytes` internally before writing it to the output file?

Comment: @TheLima No, just write the file already decrypted.

Comment: Side-note: ECB mode has very weak security. Use a secure mode, such as CBC or CTR. And consider adding authentication(either an authenticated mode, such as AES-GCM or a MAC), or you might suffer from padding oracles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm concerned your file reading code may be to blame. The [`InputStream.available()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) method only returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read. I would suggest you [Google alternative methods](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+read+file+to+byte+array) for reading an entire file to a byte array or consider using a library method such as Apache Commons [`FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File file)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToByteArray%28java.io.File%29) or [`IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29).

As a secondary check, I would recommend you perform a byte array comparison of your file contents before encryption and after decryption. I suspect they will be identical (further indicating that the file reading and/or writing is to blame).

Comment: Changed the way i read the file and how i save it and it works. Thx

Comment: As an alternative to your suggestions, what I do is create a File representation of the file and use the `File.length()` method. Like: `File file = new File("test.pdf");` and when you need to create a byte array, simply do `... new byte[(int) file.length()];`

Answer (score 5):

Your `saveDecrypt` method seems to use iText as a PDF library. You don't need to do this, in fact you should not! You treat the PDF file simply as a series of bytes when reading, so you should do the exact same thing when writing.

Simply take the bytes you decrypted and write them to a file using a `FileOutputStream`!

Comment: +1 Combine this with [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13271516/474189) about reading the file correctly and you have a complete solution.

Comment: I was writhing exactly that, but you made it quicker! Well, now I don't have to finish my writhing my (usually long) answer. --- I a [full example code](http://pastebin.com/h6DaAPha) ready, and you are free to add any part of it to your answer, if you'd like. --- [+1]